# Why opencv's SVM training is much faster than libsvm 3.18?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am comparing OpenCV's SVM and libsvm 3.18 and with the same parameters and dataset, OpenCV's svm training time is about 6-8 times faster than libsvm 3.18. I have even set the max iterations in libsvm's code.
It's said OpenCV's SVM is based on libsvm but I am wondering the difference between them. Thanks

Comment: Might be best to: a) ask on [OpenCV Q&A site](http://answers.opencv.org/questions/). b) Check in the sources of both libraries.

Comment: I just read the source of OpenCV's svm and it has some SIMD optimizations, such as calculating exp